# How to "UPDATE" Application in the google play developer console?

Tags: java, android, google-play

**I already upload one app but i don't know how to UPDATE app now**

Plz Reply

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just upload the new APK and remember to change the Version in the manifest

Comment: ya I knew it.But after this step i don't know how to update new apk version?

Comment: just upload and publish a new APK, it will do it automatically in an hour or 2 and you can then update it from the Google Play Store in your phone

Comment: My App Already complete.Now My minsdkversion is 8 & Targetsdkversion is 19.Now i want  to do My minsdkversion 11.how it possible?

Comment: change minsdkversion in the manifest.xml

Answer (score 4):

you need to have **your KEY** and sign the app with the **same name** with this key,
also make sure to **change the version of the code**. then you will be able to update.

Comment: ya I know it.But after this step I don't Know

Comment: then you just go to the tab on the left and publish the new app

Comment: My App Already complete.Now My minsdkversion is 8 & Targetsdkversion is 19.Now i want  to do My minsdkversion 11.how it possible?

Comment: Just do it, it fine just make sure you code version as well as app version goes up

Comment: How set Gujarati text in List view in Android?